# Iframe Not Respecting Height Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

I have been trying to add a javascript map to my wordpress site and for some reason the iframe is not respecting the height attribute I set.

[image: iframe map]

I've tried it using < iframe > tags and even with a plug in short code. Both lines can be seen here:

```
<iframe src="https://www.shiftins.com/county/index.html" width="100%" height="900" scrolling="no"></iframe>

[iframe src="https://www.shiftins.com/county/index.html" width="100%" height="600"]
```

And can be viewed live on this page: https://www.shiftins.com/test-page-1/

I have iframes running on other parts of my site and they work properly. How can I fix this issue?

BTW I have tried !Important and still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

On your live site the height of the iframe is set in the style with "height:150px" :

[image]

if you remove this from your css it will work like a charm :

[image]

Comment: That was definitely it. When I "inspect element" and change the height it works like a charm; however, I'm setting the height in code to > than 150px and there is no default setting in my css file. Do you know what is over riding the height?